# Deny certain GET request starting with "?rest_route=" with NGINX

Tags: nginx, web-server, http

Is there any possibility to deny/block requests where the specific GET variable `?rest_route=` is appended to the URL? I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
# location ~ ^/?rest_route {
# location ~ ^/\?rest\_route {
location ~ ^/\?rest_route {
  deny all;
}
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by using the following NGINX configuration:

```
error_page 418 = @rest_api;
if ( $arg_rest_route ) {
    return 418;
}
location @rest_api {
    deny all;
}
```